# Setting the background image for p:panel

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, panel

I am trying to display a panel with background image using the below code.

```
    <p:panel id="upperpanel" style="background-image: url(../img/login-bg.jpg)" >
```

I also tried using

```
  <p:panel id="upperpanel" style="background-image: url(/user/test/img/login-bg.jpg)" >
```

In both the cases, I am not getting the background image to be displayed. I also tried using a different image.No Luck. The image is displayed properly when I add a h:graphicImage component inside the panel.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
style="background-image: url('../img/login-bg.jpg');
```

Is going to work. Also giving `!important` inside of style property is unnecessary because any css rule that you've defined in `style` already overrides other css properties with same name. `!important` can be useful when it is used in a `.css` file.

Comment: I tried the above steps... Due to some reason, it still isnt working for me... Could there be any browser compatability issues? .. Unfortunately I am using IE8... Will have to test this in firefox

Comment: @RealChembil It can be. There are lot's of advices about IE8 and background image. But make sure you are giving the correct url, you can test it via giving  `background-image: url('http://www.google.com.tr/logos/2013/national_sovereignty_and_childrens_day_2013-1379007-hp.jpg');`. And make sure that using '' for style property and "" for css class.